# zeus rspec fails include required files, but rspec alone does fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, zeus

It's weird issue, zeus start running smoothly.

rspec spec/ does it's job flawless.

```
My spec_helper config is 
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'rubygems'

# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'email_spec'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'shoulda-matchers'
require 'shoulda/matchers/integrations/rspec'

Dir["./spec/support/**/*.rb"].sort.each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Capybara::DSL, type: :request


  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
  config.mock_with :rspec
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
end
```

I have shared contexts in spec/support/shared_contexts.rb (which is normally included). `rspec spec/` passed all tests, then `zeus rspec spec/` passed all tests and throws inclusion errors like this

`find_and_eval_shared': Could not find shared context "with signed user" (ArgumentError)

It tries to pass `zeus rspec spec/models` and then throws 'factory_girl' inclusion errors  while `rspec spec/models` do it's job fine.

It appears to look like this issue https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/175

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found this behavior was cause by

```
 require 'rspec/autotest'
```

in spec_helper.rb

Comment: Commenting out `require 'rspec/autorun'` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Posted your solution to the github issue as well: https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/134

Comment: likewise, I found with version rspec_rails 2.13.0, that I had to comment out a similar line in spec_helper: `require 'rspec/autorun'` in order to eliminate a complete meltdown of my specs.