# What's `rspec/autorun` for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I was having some problem with zeus + rspec and [the solution I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14127882/895789) says that I must to delete `require 'rspec/autorun'` from `spec_helper.rb`.

That worked great, but I was wondering what's the utility of `rspec/autorun`? It comes in `spec_helper.rb` by default, but the specs works anyway with or without it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as i understand, you would need `rspec/autorun` if you want to run specs using "ruby" command.

From [RSpec docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-13/docs/command-line):

> Generally, life is simpler if you just use the rspec command. If you must use the ruby command, however, you’ll want to do the following:
>
> ```
> require 'rspec/autorun'
> ```

Answer (score 2):

rspec/autorun installs an at_exit hook that runs your tests.  That way you can simply execute your testfiles directly rather than passing them to the rspec command (and a few other tricks, like having tests run automatically when you execute a library file).

Most setups don't need it.